# Unable to uninstall SQL Server express

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I try, I receive the following error message:

> A computer restart is required. You
>   must restart this computer before
>   installing SQL Server.

Of course, I have restarted the computer :-)  I'm not really sure how to proceed.

The version that sql server reports when I query it is: **SQL Server 10.0.1600.22 - RTM (Express Edition with Advanced )**

*Solved:* As it turns out, I had to end up uninstalling logitech's quick cam pro software.  Although the fix below did not directly resolve it, the value of that registry key led me to discovering the solution by querying for it online :-)  thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

- Open Regedit
- Find the key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"
- Rename the "PendingFileRenameOperations" value to "PendingFileRenameOperations2"

Then try the uninstaller

Comment: unfortunately this did not resolve the issue.  When I renamed that and tried the uninstaller it kept saying that I have to finish the currently pending installation/update task before uninstalling.  So I reboot again and it's saying the same thing now where it thinks I need to reboot :-(

Comment: see my update above, though this didn't directly resolve the problem, the value of the registry key you mentioned led me to find that it was quickcam software from logitech that was causing the issue.  Once I uninstalled it all was fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just emptied the key value and that worked for me.